# How to draw a rubberband or lasso to make a selection in word selection game

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am trying to put a word search game on my web page.
I see here is a beautiful example: [Embed a Word Search in Your Site](https://mywordsearch.com/embed)

I want to make similar gui, so that when the user selects the word letters from the grid by dragging mouse, it will draw a red elastic rubber band around the letters selected.

How do they do it on their web page? I tried to "inspect" the html after the band is drawn, however did not see any element added.

Can somebody give me any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JS example

```js
class App {
  constructor(div) {
    this.div = div;
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.dirty = true;
    this.prev = +new Date();
    
    this.resize();
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => this.resize(), false);
    
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
      this.touchdown(...App.getmousePos(event));
      event.preventDefault();
    }); 
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
      this.touchmove(...App.getmousePos(event));
      event.preventDefault();
    });
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
      this.touchup(...App.getmousePos(event));
      event.preventDefault();
    });
    this.canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", (event) => {
      this.touchdown(...App.getmousePos(event));
      event.preventDefault();
    });
    this.canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", (event) => {
      this.touchmove(App.getmousePos(event));
      event.preventDefault();
    });
    this.canvas.addEventListener("touchend", (event) => {
      this.touchup(App.getmousePos(event));
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  }
  
  resize() {
    this.canvas.width  = this.div.clientWidth;
    this.canvas.height = this.div.clientWidth;
    this.draw();
  }
  
  loop() {
    let now = +new Date();
    let dt = now - this.prev;
    this.prev = now;
    this.update()
    if (this.dirty)
      this.draw();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop());
  }
  
  update(dt) {}
  
  draw() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    this.ctx.rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    this.ctx.fill();
  }
  
  touchdown(x, y) { console.log("down", x, y); }

  touchmove(x, y) {}

  touchup(x, y) {}

  static getmousePos(event) {
    if (event.changedTouches) {
        return [event.changedTouches[0].pageX, event.changedTouches[0].pageY];
    }
    else {
        var rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        return [event.clientX- rect.left, event.clientY - rect.top];
    }
  }
}

class Vector {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  add(v_x, y) {
    if (y != undefined) {
      return new Vector(this.x + v_x, this.y + y);
    }
    else {
      return new Vector(this.x + v_x.x, this.y + v_x.y);
    }
  }

  sub(v_x, y) {
    if (y != undefined) {
      return new Vector(this.x - v_x, this.y - y);
    }
    else {
      return new Vector(this.x - v_x.x, this.y - v_x.y);
    }
  }

  mul(s) {
    return new Vector(this.x * s, this.y * s);
  }

  get slength() {
    return this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y;
  }

  get length() {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
  }

  get angle() {
    return Math.atan2(this.y, this.x);
  }
}

class Grid {
  constructor(width, height, data) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.data = data || new Array(width*height).fill("_");
  }
  
  get length() {
    return this.width*this.height;
  }
  
  get(x_pos, y) {
    if (y != undefined)
      return this.data[x_pos+y*this.width];
    else
      return this.data[x_pos];
  }
  
  set(value, x_pos, y) {
    if (y != undefined)
      this.data[x_pos+y*this.width] = value;
    else
      this.data[x_pos] = value;
  }
  
  clone() {
    return new Grid(this.width, this.height, this.data.slice());
  }
  
  finalize() {
    this.data = this.data.map(v => v == "_" ? String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 97) : v);
  }
  
  print() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.height; i++)
      console.log(this.data.slice(i*this.width, (i+1)*this.width).join(","));
  }
}

class Puzzle {
  constructor(width, height, words, directions) {
    this.grid = new Grid(width, height);
    this.words = words;
    this.placeWords(words, directions);
  }
  
  placeWords(words, directions) {
    const range = (N) => Array.from({length: N}, (v, k) => k);
    
    const shuffle = (array) => {
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
        }
        return array;
    }
    
    words = words.slice();
    let positions = range(this.grid.length);
    let stack = [ { 
      grid: this.grid,
      word: words.shift(),
      directions: shuffle(directions.slice()),
      positions: shuffle(positions.slice()) } ];
    
    while (true) {
      let current = stack[stack.length-1];
      if (!current)
        throw Error("impossible");
      
      let dir = current.directions.pop();
      if (!dir) {
        current.positions.pop();
        current.directions = shuffle(directions.slice());
        dir = current.directions.pop();
      }

      if (current.positions.length <= 0) {
        words.unshift(current.word);
        stack.pop();
      }
      else {
        let pos = current.positions[current.positions.length-1];
        
        let grid = this.placeWord(current.grid, current.word, pos, dir);

        if (grid) {
          if (words.length > 0) {
            stack.push({grid: grid,
                       word: words.shift(),
                       directions: shuffle(directions.slice()),
                       positions: shuffle(positions.slice())});
          }
          else {
            grid.finalize();
            this.grid = grid;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  placeWord(grid, word, position, direction) {
    let copy = grid.clone();
    position = new Vector(position % grid.width, Math.floor(position / grid.width));

    let letters = [...word];

    while (0 <= position.x && position.x < grid.width && 0 <= position.y && position.y < grid.height) {
      if (letters.length <= 0)
        break;
      
      let letter = letters.shift();

      if (copy.get(position.x, position.y) == "_" || copy.get(position.x, position.y) == letter) {
        copy.set(letter, position.x, position.y);
        position = position.add(direction);
      }
      else {
        return null;
      }
    }

    if (letters.length > 0)
      return null;
    else
      return copy;
  }
  
  wordAt(position, direction, length) {
    let word = new Array(length);
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      word[i] = this.grid.get(position.x, position.y);
      position = position.add(direction);
    }
    return word.join("");
  }
  
  print() {
    this.grid.print();
  }
}

class Selection {
  constructor(position, fill=false) {
    this.position = position;
    this._fill = fill;
    this.direction = new Vector(1, 0);
    this.length = 0;
    this.flength = 0;
  }
  
  clone() {
    return new Selection(this.position).to(this.position.add(this.direction.mul(this.length)));
  }
  
  to(position) {
    let direction = position.sub(this.position);
    if (Math.abs(direction.y) == 0) {
      this.direction = new Vector(direction.x >= 0 ? 1 : -1, 0);
      this.length = direction.x * this.direction.x;
    }
    else if (Math.abs(direction.x) == 0) {
      this.direction = new Vector(0, direction.y >= 0 ? 1 : -1);
      this.length = direction.y * this.direction.y;
    }
    else {
      this.direction = new Vector(direction.x >= 0 ? 1 : -1, direction.y >= 0 ? 1 : -1);
      this.length = direction.x * this.direction.x;
    }
    this.flength = direction.length;
    return this;
  }
  
  fill(fill=true) {
    this._fill = fill;
    return this;
  }
  
  draw(ctx, wsize, hsize) {
    let pos = this.position.mul(wsize);
    let length = wsize * (this.flength+1);
    let angle = this.direction.angle;
    //console.log(this.x, this.y, x, y, length, angle, this.dx, this.dy);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.translate(pos.x+hsize*0.5, pos.y+hsize*0.5);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    this.drawHighlight(ctx, -hsize*0.5, -hsize*0.5, length, hsize, hsize*0.5, this._fill, true);
    ctx.restore();
  }
  
  drawHighlight(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius=20, fill=true, stroke=false) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
    ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
    ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
    ctx.closePath();
    if (fill) ctx.fill();
    if (stroke) ctx.stroke();
  }
}

class PuzzleApp extends App {
  constructor(div, puzzle) {
    super(div);
    this.puzzle = puzzle;
    this.renderList(document.getElementById("list"));
    this.selections = new Array();
    this.loop();
  }
  
  renderList(parent) {
    this.puzzle.words.forEach(word => {
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      let text = document.createTextNode(word);
      li.appendChild(text);
      parent.appendChild(li);
    });
  }
  
  gridSize() {
    let wsize = Math.floor(this.canvas.width/this.puzzle.grid.width);
    let hsize = Math.floor(this.canvas.width/this.puzzle.grid.height);
    return [wsize, hsize];
  }
  
  clientToGrid(x, y) {
    let [wsize, hsize] = this.gridSize();
    x = Math.floor(x / wsize);
    y = Math.floor(y / hsize);
    return [x, y];
  }
  
  draw() {
    if (!this.puzzle)
      return;
    
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    let [wsize, hsize] = this.gridSize();
    
    this.selections.forEach(s => s.draw(this.ctx, wsize, hsize));
    if (this.selection)
      this.selection.draw(this.ctx, wsize, hsize);
    
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;
    
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    this.ctx.font = (wsize * 0.5) + 'px sans-serif';
    this.ctx.textAlign = "center";
    this.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

    for (let j = 0; j < this.puzzle.grid.height; j++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.puzzle.grid.width; i++) {
        let letter = this.puzzle.grid.get(i, j);
        this.ctx.fillText(letter, x+wsize * 0.5, y+wsize * 0.5);
        x += wsize;
      }
      x = 0;
      y += wsize;
    }
  }
  
  touchdown(x, y) {
    [x, y] = this.clientToGrid(x, y);
    
    this.selection = new Selection(new Vector(x, y));
    this.dirty = true;
  }
  
  touchmove(x, y) {
    if (!this.selection)
      return;
    
    [x, y] = this.clientToGrid(x, y);
    
    this.selection.to(new Vector(x, y));
  }
  
  touchup(x, y) {
    if (!this.selection)
      return;
    
    let word = this.puzzle.wordAt(this.selection.position, this.selection.direction, this.selection.length+1);
    console.log(word);
    if (word) {
      let list = document.getElementById("list");
      let elements = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
      Array.prototype.some.call(elements, li => {
        if (li.innerText == word) {
          li.classList.add("found");
          this.selections.push(this.selection.clone().fill());
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      });
    }
    
    this.selection = null;
  }
}

let app = null;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  const wordLists = [
    ["pear", "apple", "banana", "peach", "kiwi", "prune", "persimon"]
  ]

  const pick = (array) => array[Math.floor(Math.random() * (array.length))];

  let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
  let directions = [new Vector(1,0), new Vector(0,1)];
  if (params.get("diagonal")) {
    directions.push(new Vector(1,1));
  }
  if (params.get("backwards")) {
    directions.push(new Vector(-1,0));
    directions.push(new Vector(0,-1));
    if (params.get("diagonal")) {
      directions.push(new Vector(-1,-1));
    }
  }
    
  let puzzle = new Puzzle(8, 8, pick(wordLists), directions);
  puzzle.print();

  app = new PuzzleApp(document.getElementById("canvasContainer"), puzzle);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 7vmin;
  padding-left: 14vmin;
}

li.found {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

div#canvasContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

 @media (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
   ul {
    font-size: 4vmin;
    padding-left: 7vmin;
   }
   
   div#canvasContainer {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="canvasContainer"><canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="320"></canvas></div>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

I'll let you figure out how to change the thickness and color of the rubber band.

Answer (score 0):

The red band is an svg. It doesn't get added when you click, but rather it gets redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

I have inspected the referenced website and it seems like they draw rubber band thing in SVG. If you inspect this SVG tag while drawing:
[image: image showing svg updates]

you will notice it shows some updates.

You can use same SVG methodology. Or Another way is to use an absolute positioned div and update top, left css values based on mousedown, width based on mousemove event.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen "what" they have done.

They have created an svg element. This svg sits exactly above and covers  the entire table that contains the grid with letters. When the user clicks any letter and starts drag, they add a rectangle to the svg. Depending on how the cursor will move they do the angle transform to the rectangle. If the word is selected correctly, the rectangle survives; else, it is removed.

I need to find out now, "how" part of it.

Thanks to all for a very quick response.